# Why after include an external HTML I get 10 $digest() iterations reached in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Simply as the question said:

I do:

(current directory: `/app/registration`)

(view directory: `/app/registration/views/file.html`)

(in `/app/registration/index.html`

```
<div ng-include="'views/file.html'"></div>
```

)

Finally I get two errors in the console (in the order listed):

1. angular.min.js:2 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
2. angular.min.js:1 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

Comment: If I comment the ng-include div html <!-- -->, the error disappears.

Comment: Are you using this div inside an ng-repeat?

Comment: @Vivz no, is an AngularJS application.